# Master detail with a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, master-detail

I have a swing layout with some labels and a jTable.
On the left side, I have the jTable, and on the right side I have the labels.

I want to set the page up as a master / detail page, where the jTable is the master, while the labels act as details.

I have found a way to get the index from the jTable - my question. What kind of listener can I use to tell if the user selects a row in the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the JTable's selection model (using [`getSelectionModel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectionModel%28%29)) and add a `ListSelectionListener` to this model.

Make sure to use [`convertRowIndexToModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29) to convert the index of the selected row to an index in the table model: if the table is sorted or filtered, the view and model indices won't be the same.